How Can I Access a 32-bit ODBC Driver with Node.js? Getting "Architecture Mismatch" Error
I'm currently working on a Node.js application that needs to connect to a 32-bit ODBC driver. When I attempt to connect, I receive the following error message: "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"
I understand that this error occurs because there is a mismatch between the architecture of my Node.js application (which is 64-bit) and the ODBC driver (which is 32-bit). However, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.
Here's what I've tried so far:
1. Setting Up DSN: I created a DSN for the 32-bit driver using the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe).
2. Using Node-ODBC: I am using the 'odbc' package to establish the connection.
When I try to access the data from Excel using the same DSN, I am able to access the data without any issues.
Is there a way to bridge the architecture difference between my 64-bit Node.js application and the 32-bit ODBC driver? What steps should I take to resolve this architecture mismatch error?
I have heard about solutions like ODBC-ODBC Bridge, but I'm not entirely sure how to set it up or if it would resolve my issue. Any detailed guidance or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I expected that by setting up a DSN with the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator, my Node.js application would be able to connect to the 32-bit ODBC driver without encountering an architecture mismatch error.
